# js number format auto change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need this solution for one input.
This solution is good, but not work for one input.
I'm not js programmer ;-(

```
$('.price > div').click(function(){
    $('.price > input:eq('+$('.price > div').index(this)+')').focus();
});

$('.numberOnly').on('keydown', function(e){
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pmrotule/93zgymx9/

please, help me

Comment: What's the question ?

Comment: For which `input` it doesn't work ?

Comment: i not debug fiddle ^^ it's work,  thank

Answer (score 0):

Simply delete the other inputs and leave only:

```
<div class="price">
    <input type="text" class="numberOnly" autocomplete="off" maxlength="50" /><div>$</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/93zgymx9/136/